# crystal reports 11.5 "failed to create the Crystal Database Connector"

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 11.5 and when I try to create a report I am getting the following error "failed to create the Crystal Database Connector".

I have set up the System and User DSN in Datasouces(ODBC) and when I test the connection it comes back successful.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you,
Stefanie

Answer (score 1):

That message means you haven't setup the DSN correctly.

You need to create a System DSN on the Crystal Reports Server Machine, with your SQL server details. Then repeat create exactly the same System DSN and User DSN onto your machine:

1. Setup a connection between the database, I am assuming that database is on the server machine and you know how to create a ODBC connection:

   - Click on your 'Start' menu -> 'Administrative tools' --> 'Datasouces(ODBC)'

     Create a connection to the database there *(only System DSN)*.
   - Then move to your machine, and repeat the same process as above.

   **Note:** make sure you do a System DSN and not a User DSN under Data Source.
2. Open Crystal Reports on your machine and:

   - Click 'New standard report', You will see 'Create new connections';
   - Click on the plus sign and look where it says 'ODBC (RDO)';
   - Click the plus sign again;
   - Click 'Create new connection';
   - Once you click that, it will bring the list of databases and one of them would be what you set up in Crystal Reports server/your machine.
   - Click on it and it should connect successful to the database.

   **Note:** make sure you setup the User/System DSN onto your machine.

This should do the trick.

Comment: Stefanie, you might also need to use the 32bit driver for this if you are using a 64bit version of Windows. You can set these up using C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe and then add a data source to the 'System DSN' as Zuul has touched on above in order to connect to your database server.